# Why doesn't the sorting system actually show questions with most votes?

Tags: support, question-lists, historical-lock

I was browsing https://christianity.stackexchange.com/ today for the first time, and wanted to look at the highest voted questions. The page to see highest voted questions (as far as I'm aware) is here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes

At the moment the highest voted question has 79 votes, but that means this list is incomplete because minutes before I had come across a question with 90 votes ([Can I believe in evolution and still be a Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/130/can-i-believe-in-evolution-and-still-be-a-christian?lq=1))

I'm *guessing* it's because the 90 vote question is locked. Which is confusing because there are questions on the top voted page that are closed (why aren't closed questions also erased from this list?)

If that's the case, can I request that the sort by votes page is accurate to all questions? If not could someone explain why this is not the case?

Comment: It does appear in [search results](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=Can+I+believe+in+evolution+and+still+be+a+Christian). Anyway, that's not ordinary lock (which doesn't have such effect) but rather something called "historical lock", which is explained in the dupe